# Retrieving a photo for a contact from Google's Contact API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, binary, paperclip

I'm just pasting the google doc here:

## Retrieving a photo for a contact

To retrieve a photo for a contact, send an HTTP GET request to the photo link of this contact. The server returns bytes of the photo. For example, to get the latest version of a photo for a contact with an element:

```
<link rel='http://schemas.google.com/contacts/2008/rel#photo' type='image/*'
href='https://google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/liz%40gmail.com/c9012de'
gd:etag='"KTlcZWs1bCp7ImBBPV43VUV4LXEZCXERZAc."'/>
```

Send the following HTTP request:

```
GET https://google.com/m8/feeds/photos/media/liz%40gmail.com/c9012de
```

So I got this going and I'm getting the 'bytes' of the image. What am I'm supposed to do with this. I really don't want to save this, all I want to do is display the profile picture.

But it looks like I'm going to have to write this to a file and then upload it? So overkil Google. Why not just link to a picture... ah!

I'm using Rails 3 and I've tried writing the binary to a file and then uploading it with paperclip but I don't know the file type so where am I supposed to get that?

This is how I'm writing the file:

```
tempfile = Tempfile.new('w')
File.open(tempfile.path,'wb') do |f|
  f.write photo.body
end
```

And then I attach the file and create a new object. I know I'm going about this wrong. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As long as I know, and have been googling, Google doesnt support "link photos", they send you just the bytes

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/?hl=es#retrieving_a_contacts_photo